# check failed: status == cublas_status_success (1 vs. 0) cublas_status_not_initialized

Tags: caffe, pycaffe

When i use CAFFE to run the program something happened.
Can anyone help me solve this problem.
It seems there is something wrong with the CUDA version.
Ubuntu 16.04
CUDA 8.0.61
Can anyone tell me how to set the proper version?
Thanks a lot and really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there's some problem with CUDA.

- First Check whether CUDA is installed properly or it's installation is broken. Run some CUDA samples.

  `cd /usr/local/cuda-8.0/samples/1_Utilities/deviceQuery`

  `sudo make`

  `./deviceQuery`

Your result should be

> Result = PASS

- If it's installed properly then check whether `/usr/local/cuda` symlinked to `/usr/local/cuda-8.0`
- Check whether there's meaningful result for `ls /usr/local/cuda/lib64` command, it should list down CUDA libraries.
- Check whether `nvidia-smi` output is fine.

Comment: Glad to know that it helped you. Please 'mark answer as accepted' if it served the purpose or helped you to fix the issue.